# vscode launched from terminal cannot open scripts or graphical applications from its terminal

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, graphics, gnome-terminal, xfce

When opening Visual Studio Code from the application menu everything works fine. But not when launching it from `gnome-terminal`. Then the vscode-terminal cannot open graphical applications or even source-files with the `code` command. Doing `code file.py`, nothing happens. `firefox` gives the message `Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified`. And `gnome-calculator` gives

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-calculator:6531): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:32:23.056: cannot open display:
```

I'm using `xubuntu 18.04`, updated from `16.04`.

It is on the local computer. I think it used to work before, and works on other machines... Any ideas?